# DDD (Domain Driven Design) events and persistance

Tags: php, hibernate, doctrine, domain-driven-design

The question here is about how to handle correctly DDD DE, lets say we have this very simple example (i know that for simple projects DDD is not needed, but this is just an example). We have User (Aggregate root) and UserProfile (Value Object), so tables are:

user

```
- id
- email
- password
```

user_profile

```
- country_id
- first_name
- second_name
```

As we know our code should express behavior and should not be data-centric, so for example on one of our hexagonal side (UI browser) we have this application service to handle situation:

```
//UserService application service
public static function update($formDTO)

$user->changeCountry($form->country);
$user->changePassword($form->password);
$user->attributes = $form->userData();
$user->save(); // here we use AR not DDD ORM like; you can see this as entityManager->flush(); if you like Hibernate or Doctrine.
```

And method `changeCountry` looks like:

```
 public function changeCountry($country)
 {
     if ($this->country->id != $country->id) {
          $oldCountry = $this->country;
          $this->moveToCountry($country);
          ...->eventsManager->raise(new UserMovedToCountryEvent(
              [
                  'user' => $this,
                  'oldCountry' => $oldCountry,
                  'newCountry' => $newCountry,
              ],
          ))
     }
 }
```

Questions about `changePassword` and `changeCountry` methods:

- Should we call `save` in `$user->changeCountry()` ? Should such behavior methods (`changePassword` and `changeCountry`) persist object to storage after changing it?
- If it should then should we wrap it in transaction? I think yes, since we have here DomainEvent.
- What if there will be no DomainEvent, should we still persist object to storage? In this case this method (`changeCountry` or `moveToCountry`) used to express behavior but should it start transaction ? Is there any recomendations for this one?
- Or maybe we only should rais one domain event `UserProfileChanged` with params like `$oldInfo` `$newInfo`, but as for me this one lacks the domain.

The point is to make things correct, but without unneeded amount of persistance calls. I know that i should not think about persistance on domain layer, but getting `20` sql updates instead of `1` is not a good solution.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/07/24/doctrine_and_domainevents.html.  Basically, store the raised events inside of the AgRoot itself then use a listener to send the events when the entity manager actually persists/updates the object.

Comment: thanks for your answer; yes, i saw this one, however what would be your use-case for the quesiton if should we persist object in this `changeCountry` and `changePassword` methods ? Lets consider that we dont have good DDD ORM, and have some AR (truly it is almost the same in this question). If we should not persist object in those methods, then how we will handle entities with different database connections (once againg we have AR)?

Comment: Well I personally would never persist objects from inside the object themselves.  Not a big fan of active records.  Especially if I was trying to follow some DDD stuff.  Maybe someone else will reply.

Answer (score 1):

Domain objects should not be concerned with persistence. `Repositories` take care of aggregate persistence. You would get your aggregate from the repository, invoke methods on the aggregate and persist it again in the application layer. This leads to two database calls; one SELECT and one UPDATE - rolled up in one transaction.

```
var user = repository.GetById(userId);
user.MoveToCountry(country);
repository.Update(user);
```

I know this is just an example, but make sure you capture the user's intent. That update-method looks like your building a CRUD application, but are trying to reverse-engineer intent after the fact - which might make sense when you're refactoring etc..

Comment: well, actually as i said i made this use-case only for example, and there is no question about over-engineering. Can you tell me how to deal with this saves and updates when you will have EDA (events-driven architecture), so for example UserMovedToCountryEvent will trigger some callback which will trigger another SomeAnotherEvent and this callback? If some other entities use different database connection how to ensure then that everything works well?

Comment: Why are those other entities living in another database? Do they belong to a different bounded context?

Comment: yes, thats why i ask how to deal with this situations, when i fire Domain Event how can i be sure that everything works fine without starting a transaction? Not sure if there is a good article or some notice in book about `dont persist your entities inside entity methods`, but thats is the main question.